# How to customize scrollbar of fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have successfully achieved the popup with the help of fancybox. Now my need is to customize the popup scroll. I want to change the color of the scroll bar.
I am trying it with the help of some library but could not do it. If you can suggest anything here is what I am trying to do it.
I am using WordPress development

```
// scroll custom code
function wdm_enqueue_styles_and_scripts() {

    // Custom Scrollbar
    wp_enqueue_script(  'wdm_custom_scroll',get_template_directory_uri().'/source /jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_style('wdm_custom_scroll_css',get_template_directory_uri().'/sourc e/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css');
    // your custom JS code
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wdm_custom_js',get_stylesheet_directory().'/source /wdm_custom.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wdm_enqueue_styles_and_scripts' );
```

Here is my custom code

```
(function(){
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery(".wdm_content").mCustomScrollbar();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: have u tried scroll.js??

Comment: no what is that and where can i get it

Comment: here is the cdn path https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-smooth-scroll/2.1.2/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js

Comment: how to use it..i mean what is thr procedure to use it